# How to preserve date value with sqlSave function in R?

Tags: sql-server, r

I have a dataframe which has a date column which I am trying to insert into SQL Server. However, when I try to insert it normally without using varTypes, the values are being inserted as Microsoft.Oledb.Date . However, when I use varTypes, the code is failing with the error message

```
invalid character value for cast specification
```

Any idea how to prevent this and insert the date value as-is into SQL Server? Here is the R code that I am using

```
library(RODBC);
output<- dataset[,c("Column1","Column2","Column3","Column4","ProcuredOn")]
serverConn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=<server>;database=<database>;trusted_connection=yes;");
truncateOutput <- sqlQuery(serverConn, "drop table <tableName>")
varTypes <- c(ProcuredOn="date")
sqlSave(serverConn, output, tablename ="<tableName>",rownames=FALSE, append = FALSE)
output<-dataset
```